# Can not undo file changes in Git, Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual studio 2015, git with visual studio online.
My problem is that when I switch between branches, some random files appears in my staging area and I can't undo these changes on theese files which I didn't modified.
When I click "compare with unmodified" in VS I receive message from kdiff3 that "Files A and B are binary equal".

I tryed to "Undo changes..." in VS which resulted in nothing

I also tryed commands:

```
git reset --HARD
git checkout branchname -f
git clean -f -d
git config core.autocrlf = true
```

I can't even stash these changes. When I do that they appear right again in chages.

All devs on this project use windows 10, vs2015.

Here is my "git status" result

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Source/ClientWeb/Controllers/NoticeController.cs
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Stored Procedures/AddNoteEventType.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Stored Procedures/FixOfficialAddresses.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Stored Procedures/RecalculateLoanPreceptComponents.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Stored Procedures/RemoveCommissions.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/BankAccounts.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/CommissionWithdrawalLevels.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/ExceptionReports.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/OfficialAddresses.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/Persons.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Tables/Users.sql
    modified:   Source/Database/dbo/Views/vw_PrintJobs.sql
    modified:   Source/Web/Models/Customer/PaymentAtBranchListModel.cs
    modified:   Source/Web/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    modified:   Source/Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BankAccountModel.cshtml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

One thing that I discovered in visual studio online, is that diff shows me message "The selected files differ only in whitespace"

[Visual studio online diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oi37.png)

I'm new to git and I dont know what I should setup to avoid this whitespace problem.
I'm realy desperate now, only way how I can work is to commit these "fake changes".

**Edit**

Let's look for example at file Source/ClientWeb/Controllers/NoticeController.cs

[NoticeController.cs history, changes, kdiff3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SzIw.png)

This file has been changed lastly at 23.7.2015. I haven't touched this file neither my colleagues since that time and now it appears in my changes. Why is it so?

Comment: **Stop what you are doing** and try to understand how Git works before you lose your files! Git isn't broken and these aren't unrelated files. Nor do they need any "undoing". Files that weren't added to a branch won't be deleted when you switch from one branch to the other. What files are you talking about? Are you *sure* these files weren't added in that specific branch?

Comment: Are you saying that these files *are* commited but appear to have whitespace differences only? That's not what `some random files appears in my staging area` means. Git clients have the option of converting `\n` to `\r\n` on Windows machines. Visual Studio saves everything as `\r\n` naturally. If your repo was configured differently (which would explain the `autocrlf` change), files newly saved by VS will appear with newline differences. Just commit them

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Ive added some info to clarify my question, I hope it helps ;)